# lrzsz does not work on mac os x

Tags: macos, iterm2, zmodem

I followed these steps:

1. brew install lrzsz
2. install iterm2
3. set triggers

But when I type `sz xx.tar` at the remote machine, it popups a window for choosing the place where to save and then it displays: `**B00000000000000`

After a long time, it says: `#Sent -> xxxxx`
But I can't find the file in the place where I have choosen.

It's very weird because the rz sz works fine in SecureCRT.

Help me for this, please~

Comment: just verified installing homebrew lrzsz and minicom on 10.14. minicom session running on macosx 10.14 worked just fine, detecting ZMODEM attempt over serial connection and accepting file into the current folder has been executed from.

Answer (score 4):

`expect` is the reason why lrzsz can't be used.

If you don't use `expect` for ssh auto-logging, the lrzsz works.

Comment: What's `expect`?